# External filter in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, filter

I want to use external filter to filter a jqgrid data. In my case, using built-in filter or search box will be little strange. I have application wherein I’ll have a form which will take input and will filter the jgrid data accordingly. I have implemented code which gives me filtered data successfully but not in jqgrid. We specify URL while defining jqgrid and here I have another URL for submitting filter form. Here, the URL for filtering data and displaying data in jqgrid is different. So, how can I display the filtered data in jqgrid. I'm coding in java Hibernate.

This is my filter dialog box code:
{

```
              <form name="t_filter_form" id="t_filter_form">

              <table cellspacing="15">
                  <tr>
                <td width="50%"><label><input type="radio" value="Current_Month" id="t_filter_current_Month" checked="checked" name="filter_type" />Current Month</label></td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
                <td width="50%"><label><input type="radio" value="Yearly" id="t_filter_yearly"  name="filter_type" />Yearly</label></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><label>Enter Year:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="year" id="t_filter_year"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td width="50%"><label><input type="radio" value="Monthly" id="t_filter_monthly" name="filter_type" />Monthly</label></td>
               </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" ><label>Select Month:</label></td> 
            <td><select name="month" id="month">             
                        <option value="1">January</option>
                        <option value="2">February</option>
                        <option value="3">March</option>
                        <option value="4">April</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">June</option>
                        <option value="7">July</option>
                        <option value="8">August</option>
                        <option value="9">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%"><label><input type="radio" value="Range" id="t_filter_range" name="filter_type" />Range</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td align="right">
            <label for="from">From</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="from" name="from"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="to">To</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="to" name="to"/></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%"><label><input type="radio" value="category" id="t_filter_category" name="filter_type"  />Category</label></td> 
            </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td align="right" ><label>Enter Category:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="t_filter_category" id="t_filter_category_txt"/></td>
            </tr>
                  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><input type="button" name="filter_transaction" id="filter_transaction" value="Filter transaction" onclick="filter();" />
                        <input type="button" onclick="return close_dialog();" id="cancel_filter" value="Cancel" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </table> </form>

          </div>
```

Now when user clicks on button 'Filter Transaction' i want the grid to get reloaded. Here if user choose to filter the grid monthly then it will take the month as input and will reload the grid accordingly

This is my servlet code:

```
if(request.getParameter("action").equals("filter")){
           if(login!=null)
            {
                String query=null;
                if("Current_Month".equals(request.getParameter("filter_type")))
                {
                    System.out.println("Current month");
                    int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                    int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    System.out.println("Current month is: " +month);
                    query = "from TransactionDetails where  register_id="+hb_id+" and transaction_date>='"+year+"-"+month+"-1' and transaction_date<='"+year+"-"+month+"-31'" ;
                    System.out.println("Current month query is: " +query);

                }
                if("Yearly".equals(request.getParameter("filter_type")))
                {
                    System.out.println("Yearly");
                    int year=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year"));
                    System.out.println("Entered year is: " +year);
                    query = "from TransactionDetails where  register_id="+hb_id+" and transaction_date>='"+year+"-1-1' and transaction_date<='"+year+"-12-31'" ;
                    System.out.println("Yearly query is: " +query);

                }
                if("Monthly".equals(request.getParameter("filter_type")))
                {
                    System.out.println("Monthly");
                    int month=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("month"));
                    System.out.println("Entered month is: " +month);
                    int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    query = "from TransactionDetails where  register_id="+hb_id+" and transaction_date>='"+year+"-"+month+"-1' and transaction_date<='"+year+"-"+month+"-31'" ;
                    System.out.println("Current month query is: " +query);
                }
                if("Range".equals(request.getParameter("filter_type")))
                {
                    System.out.println("Range");
                    String from_date=request.getParameter("from");
                    String[] date = from_date.split("/");
                    from_date = date[2]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+date[0];
                    String to_date=request.getParameter("to");
                    date = to_date.split("/");
                    to_date = date[2]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+date[0];
                    System.out.println("Entered range is from " +from_date+" to "+to_date);
                    query = "from TransactionDetails where  register_id="+hb_id+" and transaction_date>='"+from_date+"' and transaction_date<='"+to_date+"'" ;
                    System.out.println("Current month query is: " +query);

                }
                if("category".equals(request.getParameter("filter_type")))
                {
                    System.out.println("Category");
                    String  category =request.getParameter("t_filter_category");
                    System.out.println("Entered category is: "+category);
                    query = "from TransactionDetails where  register_id="+hb_id+" and category='"+category+"'" ;
                    System.out.println("Current month query is: " +query);
                }
```

I'm getting correct output through the database.. but i dont how to bind this data or say get this data in my jgrid 
and this is my grid

```
function fillGridOnEvent(){
            $("#Transaction_grid").html("<table id=\"transaction_list\"></table><div id=\"page\"></div>");
           jQuery("#transaction_list").jqGrid({
                url:'http://localhost:8084/HomeBudget/TransactionController?action=show&rid=<%=hb_id%>',
                datatype: "xml",
                height: 300,
                colNames:['ID','Date','Type','Category','Amount','Comments'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'transaction_id',index:'transaction_id', width:20,sortable:false},
                    {name:'date',index:'date', width:100,sortable:false},
                    {name:'type',index:'type', width:100,sortable:false},
                    {name:'category',index:'category', width:150,sortable:false},
                    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:100,sortable:false, formatter: 'number'},
                    {name:'comments',index:'comments', width:210,sortable:false}
                ],
                paging: true,
                rowNum:15,
                rowList:[15,30,45],
                pager: $("#page"),
                loadonce:true,
                multiselect: false,
                gridview:true,
                viewrecords:true,
                caption: "Transaction"
              }).navGrid('#page',{edit:false,add:false,del:false},{multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true, showQuery: true});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I uderstand you correctly. Buth my solution is (I I have years of experience using jqGrid wizh Java and C#)

1. To define servlet/handler that returns json for jqGrid data
2. Parametrize servlet (implement filters)
3. Set new jqGrid params (params are read from form fields)

   ```
   $("#" + table).setGridParam({
       postData:queryString
   });
   ```
4. Reload jqGrid

> $("#" + table).jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid");